# Interchange integration and differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, lebesgue-integral

Let $x>0$. It can be shown that
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}t^{- \lambda}dt = \frac{\Gamma(\lambda - \frac{1}{2})}{4^{-\lambda +1}\sqrt{\pi}}|x|^{-2\lambda +1}~\lambda > \frac{1}{2}.$$
Let $-1<\lambda <0 $, then
$$ -\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}t^{- \frac{\lambda}{2}}dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}t^{- \frac{\lambda + 2}{2} }dt,$$
which is integrable. I would like to prove that
$$ -\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}t^{- \frac{\lambda}{2}}dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}t^{- \frac{\lambda}{2}}dt. $$
But I can't find integrable function $f(t)$ such that $|\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}t^{- \frac{\lambda}{2}}| \leq f(t)$. Hence DTC can't be used. How can I justify differentiation under integral sign?

I would really appreciate any hints or tips.

Comment: Idea: expand the exponential on LHS, switch the integral and the sum, integrate term by term then differentiate wrt $x$ all this valid by the usual uniform convergence arguments.  Compare with a similar operation on RHS.

Comment: $LHS =- \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x^2)^n}{n!4^n}t^{\frac{-\lambda}{2}-n-\frac{1}{2}}dt$ but $ \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{-\frac{\lambda}{2}-n-\frac{1}{2}} dt$ isn't  integrable

Comment: It is an improper integral. Expand, integrate from $\delta>0$ to $\infty$ simplify and let $\delta\to 0^+$. Here is what I am getting: $\int_{\delta}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}t^{- (\frac{\lambda}{2}-\frac{1}{2})}dt=\delta^{- (\frac{\lambda}{2}+\frac{1}{2})}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k(x^{2}/4\delta)^n}{n!((\frac{\lambda}{2}-\frac{1}{2}+n))}.$

Comment: What in the case when $n=0$? We have $\int_{\delta}^{\infty} t^{-\frac{\lambda}{2} -\frac{1}{2} - n} dt = \infty$

Comment: Are you assuming $x\ne 0$  and $-1<\lambda <0?$

Comment: I'm assuming that $x >0$ and $\lambda \in (-1, 0)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's simplify. Assume $0<p<1/2.$ Is it true that

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/t}t^{p-1/2} \, dt =  \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} e^{-x^2/t}t^{p-1/2} \, dt$$

for $x>0?$  The integral on the right is

$$= \int_{0}^{\infty}(-2x/t)e^{-x^2/t}t^{p-1/2}\,dt = \int_{0}^{\infty}(-2x)e^{-x^2/t}t^{p-3/2}\,dt.$$

Now suppose $x\in (a,b),$ where $0<a<b.$ Then the absolute value of the integrand on the right is bounded above by $2be^{-a^2/t}t^{p-3/2}$ for all such $x.$ That's a function in $L^1$ that dominates the integrands for all $x\in (a,b).$ You can now use DCT to get the desired result for all $x\in (a,b).$ Since every $x>0$ is in some like $(a,b),$ we have the result we wanted.